# Worksheet Change Event with minimum % Difference

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet change event.

Original Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Range("J12") < Range("G12") Then
      MsgBox "Oppps. Your system is not working!"
   End If
End Sub
```

I am trying to expand upon the code to:

a. Increase the range from single cells (J12 and G12) to an extended cell range (J12:42, G12:42).

b. Instead of having the change event triggered by less than (J12 < G12), have it triggered by a % difference between J12 < G12.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim diffPercent
    'Check that the data is changed between row 12 and 42 and it is even row. eg 12,14,16...42.
    If (Target.Row > 10 And Target.Row < 44) And ((Target.Row Mod 2) = 0) Then  'And _
            '(Target.Column = 7 Or Target.Column = 10) Then

        'Get the values in J ang G columns of that particular row.
        number1 = Range("G" & Target.Row).Value
        number2 = Range("J" & Target.Row).Value

        'Check for presence of both the inputs to calculate difference in percentage.
        If Not chkInputs(number1, number2) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'Calculate the percentage difference.
        diff = number2 - number1
        diffPercent = (diff / number2) * 100

        'Give alert if difference more than 10 percent
        If diffPercent > 10 Then
            MsgBox "Oppps. Your system is not working! The difference is :" & diff & "|" & diffPercent
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Function chkInputs(number1, number2)
chkInputs = False
If IsNumeric(number1) And IsNumeric(number2) Then
    chkInputs = True
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Hussain.. I have used the code as above but am getting a run-time error 13 - Type Mismatch. It is related to diffPercent = ((Range("J" & i).Value - Range("G" & i).Value) / Range("G" & i).Value) * 100.

Comment: Is there any non-number data in `J12:J42, G12:G42`?. As the error message says the data type is not matching for numerical calculation.

Comment: Hi...nope, i am dealing with values only.

Comment: Oppps...just found the error. .i have an equation in G! Would you be able to comment on how to get around this?

Comment: What equation? Can you post it here?

Comment: Thank you for your support. I have a index match function looking up a value on another sheet and returning that value to G12. =IFERROR(INDEX(User_Library!$C$9:$C$65,MATCH(Glazing_Systems!E12,User_Library!$B$9:$B$65,0)),"")

Comment: Change the function to `=IFERROR(INDEX(User_Library!$C$9:$C$65,MATCH(Glazing_Systems!E12,User_Library!$B$9:$B$65,0)),0)`

Comment: Thank you Hussain. Unfortunately, this code is proving to be tricky. The code you have kindly provided is giving me a % difference, that i really don;t need to show the user. I simply want to trigger the message based on a diffPercentage as per the original question.  Thanks again.

Comment: I guess you are totally new to vba, just change the `MsgBox "Oppps. Your system is not working! The difference is :" & diffPercent` to `MsgBox "Oppps. Your system is not working!"`

Comment: New enough but not that new. The following code still remains the issue from what i can see my end. diffPercent = ((Range("J" & i).Value - Range("G" & i).Value) / Range("G" & i).Value) * 100. The Msg is triggered, provides the popup, but this code is highlighted, now as a runtime 6 error. You have been very kind with your time Hussain, i appreciate your patience.

Comment: Share your total code. I will look into it. Along with the sample data.

Comment: Here you go...http://www.filedropper.com/mdazadhussain0812    Thanks for having a look at this for me. I have been trying to get over the challenge myself but am not a skilled VBA author. Sticking point remains a runtime error 6.

Comment: Updated the answer.